# Inject Grails Service In a JAVA class

Tags: java, spring, grails, groovy, dependency-injection

I am using Grails 1.3.4 in my project. The problem I am facing is that I am not able to inject a service which I have written in Groovy under service folder in a JAVA class I want. I have followed the documentation provided but not able to reach the solution. Can anyone please point out where I may be going wrong.

My JAVA class is

```
package com.sapienter.jbilling.server.payment;
@Transactional( propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED )
public class PSB implements IPSB {

private ISqlUtils sqlUtils;

public ISqlUtils getSqlUtils() {
    return sqlUtils;
}

public void setSqlUtils(ISqlUtils sqlUtils) {
    System.out.println("Configuring SQL Utils Service");
    LOG.debug("Configuring SQL Utils");
    this.sqlUtils = sqlUtils;
}
}
```

My Grails Service IS

```
package jbilling

import com.sapienter.jbilling.server.util.ISqlUtils

class SqlService implements ISqlUtils {

static transactional = false

@Override
void updateInvoice(Integer invoiceID) {
    println "Does Come Here.."
}

def serviceMethod() {


}
}
```

The interface the service implements is

```
package com.sapienter.jbilling.server.util;
public interface ISqlUtils {

public void updateInvoice(Integer invoiceID);
}
```

My resources.xml file is below..

```
<bean id="pSB" class="com.sapienter.jbilling.server.payment.PSB">
    <property name="sqlUtils" ref="sqlService" />
</bean>
```

I dont know much about spring and its services. Can someone point out my mistake.

The link I followed is

[Grails-Reference-Documentation](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.x/guide/8.%20The%20Service%20Layer.html#8.4%20Using%20Services%20from%20Java) and also this question on Stackoverflow which point to the first documentation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221038/injecting-a-groovy-grails-service-into-a-java-class)

Thanks

Comment: That looks right to me, what error exactly are you seeing?

Comment: @IanRoberts When I execute it with the statement like 

sqlUtils.updateInvoice(), I don't see my println statement on the server.

Comment: How are you getting hold of a reference to the `PSB` class?  Remember that the dependencies you inject using Spring configuration are only available in the specific instance of `PSB` that is created by the Spring context (i.e. the bean named `pSB`).  If you do `new PSB().someMethod()` that PSB instance won't have your `sqlService` injected.

Comment: @IanRoberts: I am doing it like    
IPSBean session = (IPSB) Context.getBean("psb");
        Integer result = session.methodInWhoseCtachBlockUpdateInvoiceIsCalled(); Like
catch (SomeRunTimeException rte) {
sqlUtils.updateInvoice()
}

Comment: In that case what you have done should work.  Are you sure you're looking in the right place for the `println` output?  Maybe try using the logging mechanism rather than just println (e.g. `log.info("in updateInvoice")`, and make sure your logging is set up right in Config.groovy).

Comment: @IanRoberts: Actually this a part of another question which I had asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796584/update-an-object-within-new-transactional-scope/11797230#comment15676018_11797230 MAybe you would get some idea referring to that as well. I just put it on bounty.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14950/discussion-between-nikhil-sharma-and-ian-roberts)