# Injecting a SpringSecurityService into a Java class

Tags: java, grails, dependency-injection

When we revise this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221038/injecting-a-groovy-grails-service-into-a-java-class) , we note that a service should  implement an interface , then , the Java class will dependent of this interface .

## But , What about Grails-services which are built-in service or existed in ready plugin ?

How to let `SpringSecurityService` implements an interface and then setting  implementations in resources.groovy

## i.e:

---

The following is not an IoC pattern because Person.java class depend on class not on interface :

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService;
class Person {

SpringSecurityService sss;


}
```

---

The following is IoC pattern : 
 If we have for example `class SpringSecurityService implements IGService{/*...*/}`

```
import grails.facade.IGService
class Person {

IGService sss;


}
```

then , in `resources.groovy` , we have :

```
  person(slm.abdennour.Person){
       sss=springSecurityService
   }
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How to inject existing Grails-Service into java class in grails project

Comment: do you have any issues with `SpringSecurityService springSecurityService` injection?

Answer (score 0):

i find solution , and i want to share it :

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService;
import grails.facade.IGService;
class CustomerSSS extends SpringSecurityService implements IGService{


}
```

then ,in `resources.groovy`:

```
springSecurityService(CustomerSSS) {
   authenticationTrustResolver = ref('authenticationTrustResolver')
   grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
   passwordEncoder = ref('passwordEncoder')
   objectDefinitionSource = ref('objectDefinitionSource')
   userDetailsService = ref('userDetailsService')
   userCache = ref('userCache')
}
```